# How do I make a Shopify app that inserts a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, script-tag

I recently started Shopify application development because I want to make an application that the user installs and puts an external JavaScript file into their theme (preferably that only load in products.liquid).

I experimented with some Rails code with ScriptTag and I get the JavaScript file to be inserted into the HTML, but it never loads.

I made the following change in app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb after this code:

```
def show
  if response = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    sess = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(params[:shop], response['credentials']['token'])
    session[:shopify] = sess
```

(AFTER) MY CODE:

```
ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(sess)
ShopifyAPI::ScriptTag.create(:event => "onload", :src => "//x.com/x/myscript.js")
```

As I said, when I inspected the element in Chrome, I see that myscript.js is inserted, but it never loads.

Is it something to do with 'async' being 'true'? Is there a way to use ScriptTag and tell that it is not an async load?

Or, is there another way around this? I searched both the API and forum for some answers but they got me very confused. Maybe I need some directions in the right path?

What should I do to develop a Shopify application in Ruby on Rails that simply inserts a JavaScript file into the owners shop? And can I make it load only in some pages, like products?

Comment: I know this is off topic, but have you considered the security implications of allowing users to upload their own JS files?

Comment: @FreddyWetson Yes, i did. Still, I really wanted to have some insight about this issue. Cheers

Comment: Do you mind sharing your JS file? Sounds like Shopify successfully inserted the script tag into the page (can be verified by looking at the source) but the JS didn't run. Maybe the entry function didn't get executed? 
Have you tried a simple sanity `console.log` check and ensured there is no errors in the console?

Also, this Shopify doc might help: https://docs.shopify.com/api/unlinked/using-javascript-responsibly

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it right. 
See document on Shopify.com: [Shopify API reference > Asset](https://docs.shopify.com/api/reference/asset#update)

> PUT takes care of both creating new assets and updating existing ones

Comment: Thanks! This is hardly explained in the Shopify docs. Seems so vital...

Answer (score 1):

Do a POST request to Shopify's [ScriptTag API](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/online-store/scripttag).

```
POST /admin/api/2020-04/script_tags.json
{
  "script_tag": {
    "event": "onload",
    "src": "https://your.dev/script.js"
  }
}
```

Curl example:

```
curl -X POST "https://$SHOP.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-04/script_tags.json" -H "X-Shopify-Access-Token: $ACCESS_TOKEN" -d "$PAYLOAD"
```

From that point onwards your script will always be included on the storefront, until the merchant uninstalls your app.